# Change ViewControllers & Pass Data in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to have my app take a picture then pass the image onto another view for editing but I can't seem to figure out how to change views, how to add an "ID" to a view in the storyboard or how to pass data between views.

Comment: Apple has a decent tutorial about communicating between view controllers at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: When you say view, do you mean view controller? Also, how are you managing the transition between view controllers? Are you doing it programmatically? Are you using storyboards?

Comment: @pmd I'm using a view controller, sorry I should have mentioned that. Also I'm using a storyboard with the two viewcontrollers, I haven't been able to manage the transition because I'm not really sure of the whole concept yet. I was using Flash Builder to create my apps but I switched to xcode so I'm still sort of learning.

Comment: I'm trying to use <i>ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.storyboard pushViewController:controller];</i> but it's throwing a error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The communication between two UIViewControllers needs to be managed manually, however, if you are using storyboards to create your app, there's some things that you need to take into account.

Let's say you have FirstViewController and SecondViewController(Lets assume you have everything set up in your Storyboard). FirstViewController will pass a UIImage to SecondViewController and they will look something like this.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)transitionToNextViewController;

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end

@implementation FirstViewContoller

- (IBAction)transitionToNextViewController;
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier"];
}

@end
```

And:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImage *image;

@end
```

You are probably wondering how are you supposed to pass the image to the SecondViewController. Well, when using storyboards, your UIViewControllers will receive a call to their method prepareForSegue:sender: . All you have to do is set the image property for the second UIViewController there.

```
@implementation FirstViewController

- (IBAction)transitionToNextViewController;
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier"];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController; // You have to cast it

    secondViewController.image = self.image;
}

@end
```

and that's it. To better understand Storyboards please read the apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318).

Comment: I would I set the Second View to know that it's name is the SecondViewController, that's one problem I've been having for a while.

Comment: How could I set the ID for the SecondViewController, like in the Storyboard or do I have to do it programmatically.

Comment: Never mind I was able to do that, I just need to reference SecondViewController in FirstViewController.

Comment: You do that in prepareForSegue:sender: method

Comment: Okay, I found out that apparently all the data that I'm sending to SecondViewController is getting cleared when the View Controller is being initialized.